# Can the product of $n$ factorials be $n$ factorial?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Are there any solutions to the equation $a_1!\cdot a_2!\cdots a_n!=n!$ with all variables being integers greater than or equal to $2$?

Comment: This very same question has been asked today.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877105/permutation-partition-counting/877142?noredirect=1#comment1809737_877142

Comment: I don't see how Bertrand's postulate fits there. Also:
$120! = 119! · 5!$, and $10! = 7!6! = 7!5!3!$

Comment: @Darth $a_1!\cdots a_{\color{Red}n}!=n!$

Comment: Yes, there are $n$ factors, and the argument I thought I had is flawed as I know see.

Comment: Oh, I see. My bad.

Comment: The problem I see is that if you have a number of the form $n=p+k$ where $p$ is the nearest prime less than $n$, then one of the factors of $n!$ would need to be $p!$. But that leaves only $n-p$ products in the factorial which would need to be equal to $n-1$ factorials.

Comment: @Semiclassical That thought can be iterative. You'd have to express $n_1 = n(n-1)\cdots (n-p+1)$ with $n-1$ factorials. If $p_1$ is the biggest prime divisor of $n_1$ then for one of the $i$, we'd have $a_i = p_1$. Then if you are lucky enough that $p_1! \vert n_1$ you'd be left with $n_2 = n_1 / p_1!$ and you'd have to express it with $n-2$ factorials. The idea is that the sequence $n_i$ shrinks faster than $n-i$.

Comment: The failure of $10!$ to give a product of more than three terms strongly suggests to me that the answer will be no.  $28!$ is even more miserable.

Comment: Aye. Even at the level of relative sizes i.e. Stirling approximation it seems pretty much untenable.

Comment: I'm amused at the rate at which this problem went from "oh, that's obvious" to "non-trivial" to "ohhh, of course!"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Legendre's formula](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Legendre's_Formula) implies that $n!$ is not a multiple of $2^n$: the power of $2$ in its prime factorization is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lfloor n/2^k \rfloor < n$.

On the other hand, the left-hand side *is* a multiple of $2^n$.

Comment: Now that's slick. Very nice. I wonder if one can use that to sharpen the 'bound' on the number of allowed factorials as well.

Comment: @Semiclassical: Are there any cases higher than $1+\log_2(n)$?